# PHP array_search

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any function which will accomplish the equivalent of array_search with a $needle that is an array? Like, this would be an ideal solution:

```
$needle = array('first', 'second');
$haystack = array('fifth','second','third', 'first');

// Returns key 1 in haystack
$search = array_search( $needle, $haystack );
```

If no function, any other functions that accept needles which may be arrays that I can use to create a custom function?

Answer (score 3):

This might help build your function:

```
$intersection = array_intersect($needle, $haystack);

if ($intersection) // $haystack has at least one of $needle

if (count($intersection) == count($needle)) // $haystack has every needle
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_intersect() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
if (empty(array_intersect($needle, $haystack)) {
   //nothing from needle exists in haystack
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = array('first', 'second');
$haystack = array('fifth','second','third', 'first');

// Returns key 1 in haystack


function array_needle_array_search($needle, $haystack)
{
        $results = array();
        foreach($needle as $n)
        {
                $p = array_search($n, $haystack);
                if($p)
                    $results[] = $p;
        }
        return ($results)?$results:false;
}

print_r(array_needle_array_search($needle, $haystack));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$needle = array('first', 'second');
$haystack = array('fifth','second','third', 'first');

if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
     echo "found";
}
```